# hex to float conversion

Tags: c#

I have a 4 byte hex number:

```
08fdc941
```

it should be convrted to a float number: 25.25, but I don't know how? I use C#

what is the correct way of converting from hex to float?

Comment: How was it converted from float to hex in the first place?

Comment: I have a running program which displays both hex and float

Comment: How you know that 25.25 == 08fdc941?

Comment: I get 25.25 as a float to be 0000CA41, and conversely, 08fdc941 to be 1.52742E-33 and 41c9fd08 to be 25.24855. Does your editor apply some rounding?

Comment: Ah wait, my bad above, since endianness means we should *always* reverse from the number got by treating it as an int or uint for 0x syntax. Still, 25.25 is 41CA0000.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
        byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(0x08fdc941);
        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        {
            bytes = bytes.Reverse().ToArray();
        }
        float myFloat = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0);
```

Comment: The endianness will be solved by the first GetBytes. You don't need the `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`.

Comment: @xanatos - are you sure? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robunoki/archive/2006/04/05/568737.aspx

Comment: The point is: 0x08fdc941 is a number. In the source code its endianness is irrelevant. It "is". When it's translated to IL and then to machine code, it becomes a "machine-specific"-endianness int. If you try to print it, you'll get 0x08fdc941. If you GetBytes of it, you'll get the "machine-specific" representation. Then you put them back as a float that has (should have) the same endianness. Unless you are on one of those machines with ints with an endianness and floats with another endianness (we will ignore those). Now. If instead of this problem

Comment: you had that those were bytes read from somewhere (disk/network)... Well... Then you wouldn't have converted them to int, or you would have done the endianness conversion BEFORE, when you did `BitConverter.ToInt32(myBytes, 0)`

Answer (score 8):

From [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx) page on MSDN "How to: Convert Between Hexadecimal Strings and Numeric Types (C# Programming Guide)".

```
string hexString = "43480170";
uint num = uint.Parse(hexString, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);

byte[] floatVals = BitConverter.GetBytes(num);
float f = BitConverter.ToSingle(floatVals, 0);
Console.WriteLine("float convert = {0}", f);

// Output: 200.0056
```

Comment: `uint num = uint.Parse(hexString, ...` yields decimal `1128792432` which is hex `0x43480170` which is what was in `hexString`. Notice the call preserved the byte ordering of `hexString`. *However* although `BitConverter.GetBytes(num)` returns a byte array, it REVERSES the byte order. You'd expect to get the byte array `{67, 72, 1, 112}` corresponding to `{0x43, 0x48, 0x01, 0x70}` but what you *actually* get is `{112, 1, 72, 67}` or `{0x70, 0x01, 0x48, 0x43}`. This bit me in the ass today.

Comment: Just remember to call `floatVals.Reverse().ToArray()` if you want to preserve the byte ordering in the conversion.

Answer (score 3):

This yields `25.24855`, which is what I think you were looking for.

```
var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(0x08fdc941);
Array.Reverse(bytes);
var result = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's the right way around, since `BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes(0x08fdc941).Reverse().ToArray(), 0)` is close.

Edit:

Incidentally, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format gives a pretty good summary of how ISO/IEC/IEEE 60559 (IEEE 754) single-precision floating-point numbers work.

Answer (score 0):

```
string hexString = 08fdc941;
Int32 IntRep = Int32.Parse(hexString, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
// Integer to Byte[] and presenting it for float conversion
float myFloat = BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes(IntRep), 0);
// There you go
return myFloat;
```

For more information, see this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-between-hexadecimal-strings-and-numeric-types