# Converting float to hex results in more digits than expected in C#?

Tags: c#, floating-point, hex

I'm going to convert a C# floating point number into 2 bytes, for instance I have number 12.4544 and it should be 0x4147, or 0x41474539, I've used bitconverter.doubletoInt64, but it gives me something weird, how can I get 0x4147?

I'm creating a MODBUS slave, and I should send each float number as only 2 bytes

thanks

Comment: A floating point number is 32-bits long, converting it to 16 bits means you're going to lose some information (half of it, really).

Comment: Anyway, why is 12.4544 0x4147?

Comment: no problem, it is in fact 0x41474539, how can I get 0x41474539? using BitCoverter.doubleToInt64 I get something stange!

Comment: Don't say "something strange", tell us what you're getting!

Comment: A double is 64 bit, not 32 bit. What are you trying to convert?

Comment: excuse me, I get 4028E8A720000000, I use BitConverter.DoubleToInt64(12.4544).ToString("X), and it gives me 4028E8A720000000

Comment: I've used a Modbus Slave/Master, it gives me this hex, also you can test it here: http://gregstoll.dyndns.org/~gregstoll/floattohex/

Comment: [hex to float conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903116/hex-to-float-conversion) Half a year ago you ask for the other way round... - wtf?^^

Comment: `DoubleToInt64` takes a `double` (`System.Double`), not a `float` (`System.Single`). So before that method is called, a broadening conversion is performed on your `float` and it will be turned into a `double`. Surely that changes the binary representation a lot! Check for yourself the difference between `BitConverter.GetBytes(12.4544f)` and `BitConverter.GetBytes(12.4544d)`.

Comment: Even though there's no "`SingleToInt32`" method, you can easily write one yourself by first calling `BitConverter.GetBytes(Single)` and then `BitConverter.ToInt32(Byte[])`. Like this: `BitConverter.ToInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(myFloatVariable))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Oh dear oh dear, I completely missed this, which is the short answer:

Use `BitConverter.GetBytes` and pass it a float, as shown [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhwsaf3w.aspx)

The long answer:

BitConverter doesn't support single precision floats, just `double`s. You'll have to create a C# "union", like so:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
class Floater
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public float theFloat;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int theInt;
}
```

Put your float in `theFloat` and look at `theInt`

Comment: thanks, how can I use it? I should make an instance of Floater?

Comment: No need, just use BitConverter.

Comment: I used BitConverter.GetBytes(12.4544f) and it gives 57 69 71 65, is it right?

Comment: I'm sure BitConverter doesn't have a bug. Convert it to hex and see what you get...