# Convert from hexadecimal to float

Tags: c#, floating-point, hex

I have a string array which has hexadecimal values in it. I want to convert it to a float array. I tried the code below but it doesn't give me the correct results:

`bufferArray` is the string array which contains hexadecimal values.

```
float[] dblBffrArry = new float[bufferArray.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < bufferArray.Length; i++)
{
    long parsed = long.Parse(bufferArray[i], NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
    dblBffrArry[i] = parsed;
}
```

Can you point an another way to do it?

Comment: I believe this has already been answered. Would you mind checking [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7903183/1991801) out. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. In that example he/she uses a hexadecimal parameter for BitConverter.GetBytes(). Is there a way to use this method with a string paramaeter?

Comment: What's wrong with your current method? What encoding is used for the strings? And how long are they?

Comment: Use the method that @MechanicalObject suggested. Use `ulong.Parse` to parse the string into a `ulong`, and then pass that value to `BitConverter.GetBytes`, as shown in the linked question.

Comment: @user1529034 I added what you asked as an answer since comments are limited. Give your feedback when you are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
float[] floatBffrArry = bufferArray.Select(s => Convert.ToInt64(s, 16))
    .Select(i => (float)i).ToArray();
```

**EDIT:**

A different interpretation of what you ask is:

```
float[] floatBffrArry6 = bufferArray.Select(s => Convert.ToUInt64(s, 16))
    .Select(i => BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes(i), 0)).ToArray();
```

It's hard to know exactly what you want when you don't give examples of inputs and outputs.

For both examples, of course there's really no need to have to `.Select` just after each other; we can do with one `.Select` if we substitute one lambda arrow `=>` into the other.

Answer (score 1):

Writing as an answer as it needs some space.

Jeppe Stig Nielsen 's answer is right and more compact than what is proposed here.

How is the following would work for you :

```
    var bufferArray = new string[] {"43480170", "41CA0000" };

    float[] dblBffrArry = new float[bufferArray.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < bufferArray.Length; i++)
    {
        uint parsed = uint.Parse(bufferArray[i], NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
        // following two lines are the missing steps in your loop
        byte[] byteArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(parsed);
        float floatValue = BitConverter.ToSingle(byteArray, 0);
        // ---- 
        dblBffrArry[i] = floatValue;
    }

    foreach (var floatValue in dblBffrArry)
    {
        Console.Write("{0}-",floatValue);
    }
```

I hope it helps.

**[EDIT - fixed link]** 
PS : I adapted the solution indicated [on this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx).